# Finding location of malicious internal IP in Wide Area Network

Tags: spam, network-scanners

Malicious Traffic detected from an internal IP in Wide Area Network (Network of multiple cities in a country).
How to find the city of that IP address in Wide Area Network?
There is no IP subnet by location. Randomly IP addresses are allocated.
ICMP traffic not allowed. Traceroute and ping won't work.
Is it possible for seeing route history for that IP address? Or any other techniques?
How to locate malicious IP by city in the network?

Comment: Are you outside this WAN?

Comment: Talk to the people that assign the IPs in the WAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tcptraceroute.  As this is TCP is will bypass most ICMP filters.

tcptraceroute sends TCP SYN packets and replies with a RST packet if it gets a SYN|ACK

https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcptraceroute

For cisco switches one could use
`Show ip route address`

Comment: Yes, but it won't work if intruder scanned from  host machine (no ports opened) and  also won't work if machine is in offline.

Comment: Thanks for response. What if multiple hops are between source and destination?